# Centering text is messing up my header

Tags: html, css

I want to center text in my header, the header takes up 100% of the view height and 100% of the width and does only consist of a solid color. When i center the text (Hello) the header is "pushed" down leaving white space and i have no clue how to fix this.

```css
#mainHeader {
  background-color: #282828;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
#hello {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 200px;
  font-family: monospace;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<header id="mainHeader">

  <p id="hello">
    &ltHello&gt
  </p>

</header>
```

(The text needs to be centered vertically when window is zoomed by default)

Comment: Can you create a JSfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/664gahL9/) and I saw the white box above the header. I added a `margin-top: 0` to the css at `#hello` and it seems to work for me. Test it out!

```
#mainHeader {
        background-color: #282828;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;  
    }

#hello {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 200px;
    font-family: monospace;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0;
}

#body { 
    margin: 0;
}
```

EDIT:

To fix what he wanted to do I used the `flex`-property to allign the items in the middle of the `header` like this:

```
#mainHeader {
    background-color: #282828;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; (vertical center)
    align-items: center;  (horizontal center)
}
```

Comment: I dont think i was clear enough, but the text needs to be centered vertically. But thanks for the answer

Comment: YES THANK YOU THANKS

Comment: Nice! I edited my answer with the solution so you can mark it as working if you want to show others the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can play with the padding-top property! Of course, I've deleted the margin top that the `<p>` adds by default...

```
#mainHeader {
  background-color: #282828;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
#hello {
  padding-top: 100px;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 200px;
  font-family: monospace;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works! This centers it on all screen sizes?

Comment: Great! If you want to do that, you should assign a % (relative) value to the padding-top property instead of a px (fixed) value... So it will be 'vertical aligned' the same distance (in relation to the top of the screen -or its parent-) on all screen sizes... Don't forget to close the question! @user

Answer (score 0):

The white space has nothing to do with centring text. That is the combination of the default `margin-top` that applies to paragraphs and [collapsing margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins).

Add `margin-top: 0` to the rules for `#hello`.

Comment: If i add margin-top: 0 the text is not centered verticaly which i want..

Comment: @user6395724 — If you leave it in then it still isn't centred vertically (unless the user coincidentally has a viewport size that means the default margin vertically centres the content).

Comment: yes but how do i make it so the text is centered vertically on all devices?